# Is there any extension or way to add a C# class in VS Code like in VS?

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-code

I've been looking at [c# main extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp) for VS Code and some others but i have not been able to add a c# class like in Visual Studio, eg: add a class with it's name space and some basic usings.

Anyone knows if there is a way to do this in visual studio code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one:

https://github.com/jchannon/csharpextensions

It does not have all what you can do on VS but its a start!